# Alarm presenting specific View Controller instead of notification for iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, notifications, clock

I want to create an alarm clock that when the time is fired, the notification provided to the user is a specific view controller, such as the alarm clock from Apple's Clock app.. Since 'UILocalNotification' was deprecated in iOS 10.0, what is the best way to approach it? Should I create it with UNNotificationRequest framework? Could anyone guide me of how should I do it? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alarm app is able to do this because it is a first-class iOS citizen. Third-party apps may not take over the lock screen (or home screen) like that.

The closest thing you could do is use the `UserNotifications` framework in iOS 10 to make it so that a custom View Controller is displayed when a user 3D-touches on the notification (or taps View on non-3D-Touch devices.)

This set of WWDC16 videos describes in detail what you can do with iOS 10 notifications.

[Introduction to Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/)

[Advanced Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/708/)

Comment: Cheers mate! Appreciated!